# Calcular el valor con la Mayor cantidad de caracteres en un array Multidimensional en una llave especifica

Tags: php, array

Estoy tratando de Calcular el *valor* con la Mayor cantidad de caracteres en un array Multidimensional en una *llave* especifica.

```
function getHighestCharAmountByKey($value,$key, $argument){
    if(strcasecmp($key, $argument['search']) == 0 &&  mb_strlen($value)>$argument[0]){
        $argument[0] = mb_strlen($value);
    }
}
$name_len=0;
array_walk_recursive($result, 'getHighestCharAmountByKey', ['search'=>'name', $name_len]);
echo $name_len;
```

el resultado es 0;

alguien me ayuda a encontrar el error, de lógica no lo veo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error estaba en que el contador debe pasarse como referencia `&$name_len` y que el argumento tambien debe ser recibido como referencia `&$name_len`:

```
function getHighestCharAmountByKey($value,$key, &$argument){
    if(strcasecmp($key, $argument['search']) == 0 &&  mb_strlen($value)>$argument[0]){
        $argument[0] = mb_strlen($value);
    }
}
$name_len=0;
array_walk_recursive($result, 'getHighestCharAmountByKey', ['search'=>'name', &$name_len]);
echo $name_len;
```